# Prism.WPF: Change MainWindow Window.Effect on Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, effects

The application is a Prism Application in WPF using C#.

I am attempting to assign a BlurEffect to the Window.Effect property when a button is clicked on the navigation menu.

I have the Window.Effect bound to a property in my viewmodel.

```
<Window ... other properties ..
        Effect = {Binding Fuzzy}>
```

and the Fuzzy property in the ViewModel.

```
private Effect _fuzzy;
public Effect Fuzzy { get => _fuzzy; set => SetProperty(ref _fuzzy, value); }
```

What I am attempting to implement is that when a button is clicked on the navigation menu that the window will blur while a UserControl is loading.

I have tried to implement the change in the Navigate method.

```
        private void Navigate(string viewName)
        {
            PerformBlur();
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", viewName);
        }

        private void PerformBlur()
        {
            BlurEffect blur = new BlurEffect();
            blur.Radius = 4;
            var ef = blur;
            _fuzzy = ef; //I've tried Fuzzy = ef too
        }
```

But that doesn't work.

I need to make the change to the window effect before it attempts to navigate, and I haven't been able to figure out how to make that happen. I have a feeling that the easiest way to do this would be to use a click event rather than a command, and then call the command in the viewmodel from the codebehind. However, that doesn't seem to be the proper implementation when using MVVM. Any suggestions on how to implement this functionality would be greatly appreciated.

(Bonus points if you can tell me how to animate the blur. lol)

Comment: I would think you can animate the blur radius

Comment: I think I would have to do that using a trigger in the Button Style since it would be dependant upon a click. If anyone can tell me how to access the Window.Effect property from a trigger in the Button Style, that might solve this issue as well. Maybe use a MouseUp or MouseDown event as the trigger event since the click is superseded by the Command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a feeling that the easiest way to do this would be to use a click event rather than a command, and then call the command in the viewmodel from the codebehind. However, that doesn't seem to be the proper implementation when using MVVM.

Invoking the command programmatically from the code-behind of the view is not any worse than invoking it from the XAML markup of the very same view as far as MVVM is concerned.

MVVM is not about eliminating code from the views. It's about separation of concerns. You can implement an entire view programmtically in a C# without using XAML at all and still be fully compliant with MVVM.

Trying to do fairly complex stuff in XAML just because you possible can is generally considered as an antipattern. Remember that XAML is a *markup* language. C# is a much more expressive and concise language so if you can solve your issue by writing some code, then this is most probably what you should do.

Comment: This approach not only ended up being the most effective but also the easiest to implement. Add in an EventAggregator and the pattern is also easily reusable. Thank you for pointing out my improper understanding of MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the prism source code, I can see iregionmanager is full of abstracted interfaces.

( Wow. I don't know why it still surprises me but prism is very complicated ).

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Regions/IRegion.cs

That includes IRegionNavigationService

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Regions/IRegionNavigationService.cs

You could therefore override pretty much any functionality you like, if you wanted to.

Notice though, the two events :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when the region is about to be navigated to content.
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler<RegionNavigationEventArgs> Navigating;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when the region is navigated to content.
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler<RegionNavigationEventArgs> Navigated;
```

Looks to me like "all" you need is a reference to your region navigation service in the view.

Handle those two events to set blur then remove blur.

You could then do navigation in code behind or viewmodel. Whichever suits.

If you wanted to decouple viewmodel from view, you could use the eventaggregator.

There is another option though.

You don't explain exactly what you have there.  So let's imagine and consider a better way to do this.

Say you have a set content of a set control you're always navigating. That's being switched out as you navigate for a new view whose datacontext is a new viewmodel.

You could bind an attached property from the window to the datacontext of that.
In that property you can have a change callback.

In a base viewmodel you could add an IsLoaded bool property which is initialy false.

When your dependency property callback returns null or false then you blur.
You change the viewmodel property to false in the current viewmodel when you start to navigate. The window blurs.  The content is switched out and you get a new viewmodel. Once navigation completes you set that ILoaded true.  You callback un blurs the window.